# Trivial perfect codes

Tags: coding-theory

A text book I'm referring define trivial perfect code as follows:

> The binary repetition code of length n, where n is odd is a perfect (n, 2, n) code. Such codes, together with codes which contain just one codeword or which are the whole of (Fq)^n are known as "trivial perfect" codes.

I understand how a code with just one codeword can be perfect, but how does whole of (Fq)^n qualify for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perfect code is, by definition, a code such that $F_q^n$ is the disjoint union of balls of some fixed radius centered on the codewords. The whole of $F_q^n$ qualifies --- trivially --- by taking that radius to be zero.

Comment: ah. radius == 0. Thank you @gerry-myerson